# How to dynamically Load in Mvc Controllers from a Nuget package. Docker Container Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, docker, .net-core

I have multiple microservice endpoints (Gateway) that share common MVC controllers. I would like to extract these controllers to a Nuget package so that they can be shared across the projects and use FeatureManagement to enable/disable the controllers/methods.

Referencing a library directly (same solution) works as intended.
The controller assembly loads and is added via the code below:

```
services.AddMvc()
            .AddApplicationPart(Assembly.LoadFrom($"{Location}/{Configuration["ControllerLibrary"]}"))
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

The first issue I had when extracting the lib to Nuget was the .dll. I had to add the following to the .csproj file.

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

This is a bit heavy (a blanket copy all) but acceptable but also was the first 'code-smell' that caused me to feel I was approaching this the wrong way.

The issue occurs when running inside a docker container as the reference location doesn't appear to be the same as when running in windows(IIS/IISExpress)/LXC containers.

When running (attempting to run) inside a docker container, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly '/app/xxx.xxx.Endpoints.Mvc.dll'. The system cannot find the file specified.at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromPath(IntPtr ptrNativeAssemblyLoadContext, String ilPath, String niPath, ObjectHandleOnStack retAssembly)
at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath(String assemblyPath)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
at xxx.xxx.Client.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in /src/xxx.xxx.Client/Startup.cs:line 25
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
at xxx.xxx.Client.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/xxx.xxx.Client/Program.cs:line 10
```

As the container cannot start, I am unable to enter the file director/bash in to see what's going on but understand that the dll isn't where I am expecting it to be (the same location as the executing dll).

```
private static readonly string Location = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

I am a novice with Docker but haven't found anything that would enable me to easily debug the issue.

Firstly, I would like to find out why the different behaviour so I can better understand docker and any potential resolutions. Also, it would be nice to see if I am approaching this the right way or if there are better alternatives (It is starting to feel like a bit of a hack/convoluted workaround).

Thanks for taking the time to read :)

Comment: Have you included the DLL copy in your Dockerfile?

Comment: Try to change docker file entry point to /bin/bash instead of dotnet and explore the files inside.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is embarrassing.

The issue turned out to be that the context inside the docker container did not have permission to access the Nuget feed (Hosted in Azure Dev Ops). As such, the file could not be found was because the restore was failing but NOT causing a breaking/the final error (it did list the error in the console).

The error in the original post was a symptom of this, becoming a little bit of a red herring as I didn't examine the console closely enough.

I needed to add a NuGet.config file (pointer and user/PW), along with the reference to copy it to the correct location (dockerfile) in the docker container.

However, that wasn't the end of the story as it appears our private NuGet server (Azure Dev Ops) had some weird security permissions set somewhere for users. We needed to use the admin account in the end (via key/token) to finally get it to work.